# netsh wlan command not found in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

am not able to find netsh wlan command to connect to wireless networks. 
How do I install this service on windows xp ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't find it because the `netsh wlan` command exists only in Windows Vista, Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008.

The `netsh` from Vista will not work on XP.

From [Technet Article from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744889%28WS.10%29.aspx) explaining `netsh wlan`:

> Applies To: Windows Server 2008,Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> ...
>
> The commands documented in the Netsh WLAN reference for Windows Server® 2008 can be run - as documented – on computers running Windows Vista®.
>
> Likewise, the commands documented in the Netsh WLAN reference for Windows Server® 2008 R2 Release Candidate (RC) can be run - as documented – on computers running Windows® 7 RC.

Answer (score 1):

Symantec's free WLAN.exe can be used to export/import WLAN settings and connect/disconnect WLAN on Windows XP SP2/SP3: How to Capture and Deploy WLAN Profiles (on Windows XP SP2 or SP3) http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-capture-and-deploy-wlan-profiles

Answer (score -3):

netsh should be available for you on Windows XP. Check C:\Windows\System32 for the exe.

Make sure your wireless device is found and installed properly.

Make sure you have at least service pack 2 installed as it has some updates for netsh.

Thanks,
-Mathew

Comment: This is incorrect. SP2 does not add Vista functionality to XP.